# Confusing variable in auto generated Makefile by qmake

Tags: makefile, qmake, qt4.8

I recently started to take over a QT4.8 project for embedded Linux. After using qmake and .pro file to generate Makefiles in the project, it could not build properly.

The Makefile.Debug snippet causing problem is as following:

```
{..\GriduiWin}.cpp{debug\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fodebug\ @<<
    $<
<<
```

For `<<` in the end, make is complaining for the missing tab at the beginning.

For `@<<` at the end of the second line, I couldn't figure out what is the issue here. The error message is `<< was unexpected at this time.`

What does @<< mean in Makefile? Is this specific from qmake generated files? Or is this a reasonable syntax? How could I deal with this error? Thanks for help.

Comment: That syntax is not valid makefile syntax.  I don't know much about qmake, but it's supposed to generate makefiles.  If these are the _input_ files you shouldn't be trying to run make on these files.  You should be running make on the generated makefiles.  If these are the generated files then you're generating files for a different type of make.  Maybe these are `nmake` makefiles?  Don't know.

Comment: The project checked out from revision includes the .pro file for qt4.8. Original developer used VS 2008 and cross compile for embedded arm linux on Win 7. From my Google search, ```qmake``` is probably the only command that generates makefiles. I'll double check with ```nmake```.

Comment: Looking at `@<<` I'd hazard a guess and say there's supposed to be something between the `@` and the `<<` -- and possibly after the `<<`.  This almost looks as if there are `make` variables being used in the expression but which are undefined.  Just guessing though.  Difficult to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: @G.M. This is my first QT project ever. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to create such example based on our current  configuration. I just qmake with the .pro file included and the above lines are from the generated Makefile.Debug, as well as Makefile.Release.

Answer (score 0):

This generated Makefile turns out to be for `nmake` instead. Errors no longer shows when compiling with Microsoft Visual Studio command line tools. Thanks to MadScientist for the hint.